mocking a self-defined decorator which has a function in it
I am trying to unit test a flask application route that calls a function that is wrapped by a self-defined decorator called verify_jwt.
This decorator is defined in the same module where are defined functions called by routes.
The verify_jwt decorator is used as a decorator to protect routes that require authentication. It verifies the JWT in the request (by the function verify_jwt_in_request defined in flask_jwt_extended) and calls the decorated function if the verification is successful.
Otherwise, if the verification fails, it logs an exception and returns an unauthorized response.
I have tried different approaches, that I have found on Stack Overflow and on other websites, as patching the decorator before importing the module with the function under test, mocking the verify_jwt_in_request function inside the decorator, and son on, but none of these were successful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Instead of trying to mock the decorator (verify_jwt) I have mocked the function in it (verify_jwt_in_request) - I have got the idea from Stack Overflow as well.
For the decorated function to be executed verify_jwt_in_request has to return nothing or an exception in case the verification fails.
Below is how I have done it:
> def mock_verify_jwt_in_request():
>    return 
 
> with patch('flask_jwt_extended.verify_jwt_in_request', mock_verify_jwt_in_request):
>    from your_module import your_function

This method also works if the decorator and the functions under test are in the same module.
